# Authenticate external website using previous logged on website asp.net

Tags: c#, authentication

There are two websites (siteA and siteB) which hosted in same network. Users can logged in to siteA using their active directory login details. Then there is a link to siteB. If user click on that link siteB should skip login page of siteB and redirect in to home page with that user. And if user direct visit siteB it should be login page.

Site urls 
siteA : siteA.domain.com
siteB : siteB.domain.com

in site A there is a link to siteB = http://siteB.domain.com (no query string parameters). And I can not do changes in siteA.

this is what they asking. How could I do this. cookie sharing or any other way? if there is no other way how with query string?

(Both sites can be access through internet.)

Answer (score 1):

Install siteC which would be the Active Directory Federation Services 2 (ADFS2). Optionally switch it to Forms Authentication so that users will have to type their username and password from the Active Directory. ADFS2 is a free addon to Windows Server, you can download it from MSDN.

From this moment, ADFS will be responsible for authenticating your users and passing this information to other sites. Your users authenticate only once, the very first time they log into one of your sites, A or B.

Then, learn how federated authentication works, make minor changes to your sites A and B. There is a free ebook on that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx

Comment: how could I approach this? do users need to logged in to siteC first or if user visit siteA will it ask ADFS2 login details?

Comment: If you make minor changes to A and B to support so called "federated authentication", A and B will take care of redirecting users to ADFS when necessary. Just spend some time to read the ebook if you are new to this but this is definitely a right track.

Comment: yeah I am new to this, I read that first and get back to you if I got problem, thanks very much